# Query error in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
SELECT product_key.contact_email, product_key.client_name, product_key.status, product_key.key, payment.paymentdate, product_key.id, MAX(paymentdate) AS latest_payment, DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS expiration_date 
FROM product_key LEFT OUTER JOIN payment ON payment.keyid=product_key.id 
WHERE product_key.status = 'purchased' AND expiration_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) GROUP BY product_key.id 
ORDER BY client_name asc
```

This is my query. I know I can't use an alias in a WHERE Clause since WHERE is first read before the SELECT. But even if I use something like this:

```sql
SELECT product_key.client_name, DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS expiration_date 
FROM product_key LEFT OUTER JOIN payment ON payment.keyid=product_key.id 
WHERE DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND product_key.status = 'purchased' 
GROUP BY product_key.id 
ORDER BY client_name asc
```

Still an error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us the error just as good practice?

Comment: If you receive an error what is it? @Fastidious not just as good practice, but necessary in my book.

Comment: @andy-g PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: I made this query to get an email that should equivalent in my condition that if the 'expiration_date' is equal to 'DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)', I should send a notification telling that his subscription will expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an aggregate `MAX()` you should put it `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`. Assuming that other than that your query is correct and functional you can rewrite it like this

```sql
SELECT product_key.client_name, 
       DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS expiration_date 
  FROM product_key LEFT OUTER JOIN payment 
    ON payment.keyid=product_key.id 
   AND product_key.status = 'purchased' 
 GROUP BY product_key.id 
HAVING DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
 ORDER BY client_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT product_key.client_name, 
       DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS expiration_date 
  FROM product_key LEFT OUTER JOIN payment 
    ON payment.keyid=product_key.id 
   AND product_key.status = 'purchased' 
 GROUP BY product_key.id 
HAVING expiration_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
 ORDER BY client_name
```

Comment: It has no error. However, it did not get what I want. I should get: one contact email(e.g. name123@yahoo.com), where the 'expiration_date' = September 5, 2013.


I just don't get it.

Comment: In order to help you with that you have to provide more information. Specifically actual table schema (for both tables) and relevant sample data that should yield above mentioned record.

Comment: This should just reflect this one result since I made it just for that:

From my table 'payment':
paymentdate = August 5, 2013
expiration_date = September 5, 2013
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) = September 5, 2013

From my table 'product_key':
contact_email = xxx123@yahoo.com
client_name = Karl Angelo Pavia

So I'm assuming to get this data using the query.

Comment: @user2710526 If you want to helped please consider to spend a few minutes and help those who help you and provide all necessary information by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18436028/edit) your question. See how other OPs do that http://stackoverflow.com/q/18010870/1920232

Comment: I've solved it. Thanks for helping. :)

Here's my query:

`SELECT b.client_name, DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(a.paymentdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AS expiration_date FROM payment a LEFT OUTER JOIN product_key b ON a.keyid=b.id AND b.status = 'purchased' GROUP BY a.keyid HAVING expiration_date = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY b.client_name asc`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an alias defined in the `select` clause in a `where` clause.  But that is ok, because you want to use `having` clause:

```
SELECT pk.contact_email, pk.client_name, pk.status, pk.key, p.paymentdate, pk.id,
       MAX(paymentdate) AS latest_payment,
       DATE_ADD(MAX(paymentdate), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS expiration_date 
FROM product_key pk LEFT OUTER JOIN
     payment p
     ON p.keyid = pk.id 
WHERE pk.status = 'purchased'
GROUP BY pk.id 
HAVING expiration_date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
ORDER BY client_name asc;
```

You *can* use the alias in the `having` clause.  Also, I added table aliases to your query to make it more readable.

Comment: :It has no error. However, it did not get any result either. I manually set my latest 'paymentdate' to September 5, 2013 to one of my data so it should reflect when I run the query but I got nothing.